# No module named '...' python

Tags: python

I have a directory called project set up like this:

**Project**

```
--directory:src--  
--directory:testscripts--  
--directory:config_files--  
RunPCS.py
```

and within src, it is set up as:

**src**

```
parse_files.py  
parse_json.py  
process_xml.py  
__init__.py
```

in RunPCS.py I have `from src.parse_files import parse_files` and 
`from src.parse_json import parse_json`

in parse_json.py I have `from process_xml import process_xml` (since they are in the same directory)

but i get the error `no module named process_xml`. does anyone know why this error shows up?

Comment: Please be specific about which version of Python -- the relative-import rules vary. See, ie. https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html -- introducing explicit relative-import syntax in 2.5 (which you probably should be using here).

Comment: i'm using python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

for the import statement, use

```
from .src.parse_files import parse_files
from .src.parse_json import parse_json
```

in your parse_json.py

```
from .process_xml import process_xml
```

Comment: Is it still in the future as of 3.4? I thought this became part of the language proper with 3.0.

Comment: well OP only commented it after I place my answer, so don't need the import absolute_import

Comment: thanks for the answers. however when i used "from .src" it gives the error ' ' not loaded, cannot perform relative import. when i make the change "from .process_xml import process_xml" and use src instead of .src it fixes the issue however